# TensorFlow/Keras - how to transform text properly?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to create a model which decides whether a main subject of a sentence is a Prague city.

Sentences are in Slovak language. I.e:

> "V Prahe bolo dobre", "Praha je v Česku"...

My `csv` file looks like this:

```
Praha je v Česku,1 
Chodím do Blavy,0 
Neviem čo to je za vetu,0
Pražský hrad,1
```

As you can see the word Prague has many forms so I don't want to just substitute every word from csv to some number. My goal is to detect it on character-level.

Tried this:

```
train = pandas.read_csv("prague_train_set.csv",
                        usecols=[ "title"])

train['title'] = train['title'].fillna("None")
train['title'] = le.fit_transform(train['title'])

results = pandas.read_csv("prague_train_set.csv",
                        usecols=["result"])    

# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=1, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
# Compile model
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
# Fit the model
model.fit(train, results, epochs=150, batch_size=10, verbose=2)
# calculate predictions
predictions = model.predict(train)
```

But the output is like it was total random:

**EDIT** approximately 1/4 of titles is about Prague

```
...
Epoch 145/150
 - 0s - loss: 0.1826 - acc: 0.7589
Epoch 146/150
 - 0s - loss: 0.1827 - acc: 0.7589
Epoch 147/150
 - 0s - loss: 0.1826 - acc: 0.7589
Epoch 148/150
 - 0s - loss: 0.1827 - acc: 0.7589
Epoch 149/150
 - 0s - loss: 0.1827 - acc: 0.7589
Epoch 150/150
 - 0s - loss: 0.1827 - acc: 0.7589
```

I think it's because `train['title'] = le.fit_transform(train['title'])` trasforms whole sentences into numbers but not sure. Do you know what to do?

Comment: How big is your csv file?

Comment: Approximately 5000 articles

Comment: You’re doing a binary classification, right? I would start by using 'binary_crossentropy‘ as your loss function, not mean square error, as you’d want to use that if it’s linear regression/output layer...which doesn’t make sense to use here. Also, have read about words2vec?

Comment: If `le` is a label transformer, then you're right. Also, `input_dim=1` means that each sample is represented as just a vector with one value. If you don't want to use transfer learning and you have a pretty small training set, I would help classifier by tokenizing sentences, padding tokens to the same length, and using convolution with the kernel size equal to this length. This way you might be able to recognise whether a sentence contains the name of the city at least.

Answer (score 0):

SInce you want to classify on the character level I suggest using a CHAR-CNN:

https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5782-character-level-convolutional-networks-for-text-classification.pdf

To proprocess the data you just have to do two things:

1)  Get a set of characters that you want to use - this may be every character (punctuation included) or just the most common characters

2) Establish and save encoding of characters into integers. If you are not using all the characters inside the set defined in 1), also create an integer for unknown characters

3) Trim or pad the sentences to have a standard length

The following is a trivial example of a CHAR-CNN designed to predict if 'a' is present inside a string:

First preprocessing the data:
Code for this may look like:

```
from random import choice

lowercase = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
x = [''.join(choice(lowercase) for _ in range(10)) for _ in range(5000)]
y = [int('a' in i) for i in x]

char_set = set(char for word in x for char in word)
encoding = {i: char+1 for char, i in enumerate(char_set)} # let 0 be the unknown character
```

Save the encoding dictionary somewhere and you can transform all of your inputs into integers:

```
x = [[encoding.get(char, 0) for char in sentence] for sentence in x]
```

Then pad the sequences:

```
max_len = max(len(i) for i in x)

from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
x = pad_sequences(x, maxlen=max_len)
```

Each sentence becomes a list of integers.

After the data is preprocessed you will build the model. Since our preprocessed data is a list of integers we will encounter one big issue:

If "a" => 2 and "b" => 7, the model will naively assume that "b" > "a" even though this is not true.

To combat this (and to have the model build internal representations of each character), I will use an embedding layer to map each character to an N dimensional vector.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Embedding, Conv1D, GlobalMaxPooling1D, Dense

VOCAB_SIZE = len(encoding) + 1
N_VECTORS = 12

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(VOCAB_SIZE, N_VECTORS, input_length = max_len))
```

At this stage we can use Conv1D layers to start detecting features. Unfortunately I cannot give you exact hyperparameters because I don't have access to the entirety of your dataset, so this is merely an example model.

```
model.add(Conv1D(64, kernel_size=(3,)))
model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=(3,)))
```

Since we're dealing with a 3D tensor at this stage (embedding layer returns a 3D output of `(batch_size, max_len, N_VECTORS))`, and we want to return a 2D output `(batch_size, one_or_zero)`, we max pool the output and feed it into a dense layer.

```
model.add(GlobalMaxPooling1D())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')) #sigmoid activation to return number from 0-1

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
model.summary()
model.fit(x, y, epochs=1000)
```

Finally for your convenience I have uploaded an un-broken-up copy of the code I used on pastebin: https://pastebin.com/SvvJaQJv. Running the model on the toy dataset gets you 100% accuracy within 2 epochs.

I hope that this answer gives you a better understanding of preprocessing your text for nlp and some techniques you can use. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to try this approach. I've created a new code which seemed to run much better but results are not satisfying - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53693188/keras-tensorflow-high-acc-bad-prediction

Comment: What do you want me to do? Copy paste this into your new question?